# Deactivate Linux Shell to prevent "blind" login on router

Tags: linux, router, usb, embedded-system

Today I analyzed my home router.

I connected a keyboard to the router's USB port, which is usually used for mass storage devices.
However, I pressed the key combination to reboot a Linux system from TTY (<Ctrl>-<Alt>-<Del>) multiple times. Afterwards the router actually rebooted.

Now, for me this is a strong indication I can blindly access a TTY with the keyboard. If I knew a username and a password I'd most likely be able to login.

To prevent this, the router manufacturer could disallow USB Keyboards.
But else what could they do to prevent this behaviour? Is it sufficiant to disable all TTYs? Can I build a Linux without a login possibility?

Comment: The threat model is a hacker, who wants to hijack the router, that was provided by his ISP

Comment: That's a threat for the ISP, not for the person whom the router was given to.

Comment: Yes it is. But what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97411/discussion-between-mechmk1-and-0xaffe).

Comment: If someone has sufficient physical access to plug in a keyboard, they can also power-cycle it by unplugging it, hit the reset button to reset the admin password, or even take it apart and steal all of the existing data from the flash. What possible attack do you think you'd stop by disabling the keyboard?

Comment: Why are you using your ISPs router?  That's almost always a bad idea for a more tech savvy/security conscious user.  Let your ISP worry about their router security, and you should just replace it with a router that you can install open firmware on and fix all of this yourself...

Answer (score 1):

> But else what could they do to prevent this behaviour?

Several possibilities:

- Disable HID drivers in kernel.
- Disable TTY support on kernel
- Disable getty on TTY.
- ...

> Is it sufficiant to disable all TTYs?

Should be, yes.

> Can I build a Linux without a login possibility?

For sure. Most embedded firmware are built with Yocto or Buildroot. Using these tools you can do what you want. One can build a system that will only launch a custom init system that only implements what is needed.

Comment: Would removing the password from the `passwd` file be sufficient, assuming the image is read only?

Comment: usually, password aren't stored in `passwd` file but in `/etc/shadow` file. Removing password from here means "no password" and, as a consequence, is a bad idea...

Comment: Right.  I currently remove root from both of these files for production units. Trying to log in with root results in bad login as the user doesn't exist. This seems good enough for me, but I'm not sure if there are loopholes.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the system secure

1. getty (a tty service) to be removed
2. usb drivers for keyboard to be removed
3. users (root or other users) should have a strong password

But what happens if need to debug a system in the market, then we should flash an image that supports these interfaces